# in the wind; with the wind

Tags: vocabulary

> (a) The bandana on the end of his rifle flapped **in the wind**. 
>   (b) Her hair blew up toward the sky **with the wind**. 
>   (from COCA)

The bandana and her hair moved *in the wind* or *with the wind*. ‘*With*’ seems to be “used to indicate the specific thing or person that is being referred to (-> refer to: "to have a direct connection or relationship to (something).” ‘*In*’ seems to be “used to indicate the conditions that are around someone or something.” [- All definitions are from Merriam-Webster's Learner's dictionary.]
(1) Is my supposition right? 
(2) Are they used with distinctly different nuance or virtually interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that "in the wind" implies multiple gusts of wind. The wind was blowing, and whenever it blew, the bandana flapped around; but "with the wind" suggests a single gust. Marilyn Monroe's dress was up around her thighs with the wind.